# How to pass element finder resolved by ElementArrayFinder in protractor?

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I want to find a group of elements and pass references to them (how?) for later use so I don't have to "find them" again.

For example, having a dom

```
<div class='row'>
 <label>Foo<label>
 <input type="text"/>
</div>
<div class='row'>
 <label>Bar<label>
 <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

I query for each row and I try to remap results for easy assertions later on.

```
const rows=$$("div.row").map(row=>({
   label: row.$("label").getText(),
 //   element:row <--- this causes stackoverflow
})
```

as you can see, I want  to simple remap label text to a plain object and I try to store `element` which would be a reference finder for that particular row. The label parts works well but, this 'element' causes stackoverflow. The reason why I want to store such finder is to be able to easily use it later on like that:

```
const values=["v1","v2"];

Promise.all(rows.map((row,idx)=>row.element.$('input').sendKeys(values[idx])));
```

In principle this should work, however I dont know how to store reference to the actual row element found by `$$`. How such unique identifier can be obtained and then used in protractor API?

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
const rows = $$("div.row");
const text = await rows.getText() // ['label1', 'label2', 'label3']

let elemMap = text.map((row, idx) => {
  label: row,
  elem: rows.get(idx)
})
```